# Menu breaks when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question didnt give me any answers :/

```js
// Hello there
```

Comment: Looks identical on codepen (desktop) and in the provided screen recording. Where is the breakage?

Comment: @terrymorse keep watching the video until the end. The navbar breaks when you click it a second time. This surprised me as well because before it used to break on the first click.

Comment: I still don't see any breakage. Can you make a still screenshot of it? I also tried codepen on iPhone—looks fine to me.

Comment: I don't see anything when I click the Run code snippet. Please include the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue (a [mre]) in the snippet.

Comment: @HereticMonkey added the code

Comment: @terrymorse I provided the screenshots, can you see the breakage now?

Comment: The snippet works fine on my Pixel 3 on Chrome 81... In fact it looks better on the snippet (full screen) than it does on the pen... Might have to do with how CodePen runs things. I'd run it from a local server and test it that way...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've done that by sharing it via ngrok but the problem still persists. Maybe it is a problem with my phone operating system (iPhone 7)?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely screwy-looking in codepen. I got it to look correct on the codepen by tweaking the the transition and transform settings:

```
header div div#menu_btn .menu_cont span {
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-out; /* transform instead of all */
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  /*  transform-origin: right center; */
}

header div div#menu_btn .menu_cont span.one.transition {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 6px; /* changed */
}
header div div#menu_btn .menu_cont span.two.transition {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 5px; /* changed */
}
```